# remove lines/contents that matches a pattern in Linux

Tags: linux, comments

I want to remove all lines and contents in comments i.e. "--" from a file. For example my data is

```
---------
--Text1
--Text2
---------
Text3 --Text4
Text5
```

and my output should be

```
Text3
Text5
```

I tried **sed '/^--/d' test.txt** and it removed all lines that starts with -- but I want to remove all contents after -- as well like line 5 above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
$ echo 'foo--bar' | perl -pe 's/--.*//' 
foo
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.

`s/--.*//` : Replace literal `--` followed by any character repeated 0 or more times with nothing (= delete comments).

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)